# Div being pushed down by invisible force

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a thumbnail grid. Each thumbnail can have either one of two different height, but I want the whole row to have the same height

[image]

As can be seen, because the last two thumbnails are higher, the rest get's pushed down.

When I inspect it with Google Devtools, no padding or margin has been added, they're just being forced down somehow

CSS:

```
.video {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 220px;
  height: 250px;

  margin: 0 0 15px 15px;

  h4 {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

  .thumbnail {
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    // box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -6px;

    .caption {
      word-break: break-all;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <div class="videoList">

      <div class="video">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/s_vi/YXQdrjJiQjY/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=CNjOtKgF&amp;rs=AOn4CLAx8dW9kP4W6XdVeCR73QmLOEOdNw" alt="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4><span class="title">My Slideshow</span></h4>
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>1 views</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 0</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> 0</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 0</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="video">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/s_vi/Ii7FfPgDU6A/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=CNjOtKgF&amp;rs=AOn4CLAU-ezif1lm8rXcVNRePjnfVhGvTA" alt="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4><span class="title">My Slideshow</span></h4>
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>1 views</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 0</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> 0</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 0</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="video">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/s_vi/GB9syW4zI2o/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=CNjOtKgF&amp;rs=AOn4CLDbBXF49SYPGVhCKJ6QqYcwP3xpEA" alt="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4><span class="title">My Slideshow</span></h4>
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>0 views</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 0</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> 0</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 0</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="video">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/s_vi/b7dK2DEMkyI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=CNjOtKgF&amp;rs=AOn4CLC6UBWeTho-vmmSozu-CG1Zno88vQ" alt="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4><span class="title">My Slideshow</span></h4>
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>1 views</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 0</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> 0</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 0</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="video">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        *<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/s_vi/9nizjdeEecE/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=CNjOtKgF&amp;rs=AOn4CLC5VfvmjPALw-K5COknauUE2fTORg" alt="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4><span class="title">John Lennon - Imagine (rock instrumenta...</span></h4>
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>38 views</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 0</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> 3</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 0</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align:top` to the `.thumbnail` class for alignment.

Comment: Didnt work unfortunately

Comment: Then a demo we can test would be useful. Or you could try the alignment on the `.video` class.

Comment: Its becoz you have different image size, If last two div's replaced by any other 2 divs, its working fine

Comment: @Paulie_D Setting in on .video worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because other divs have longer titles than others and your div are aligning them bottom by default.To fix this problem you'll need to add `vertical-align:top;` to your class `.item`, if not I think the class is `.thumbnail`

```
.item {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: The default is actually `baseline` not bottom.

Answer (score 0):

add vertical align to video class:

```
vertical-align:top
```